# SendLogsRequestListener failure in worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, native, worklight-analytics

I am re-implementing an existing worklight system. We have already have a hybrid version. We have decided to re-implement the Client side in pure native. The native client seems work fine.

However, the server seems to be quite unstable - sometimes we don't get a server response after invoking an adapter, sometimes we do get. I have checked the DDMS/Android console. And a Error/Exception was found. Any comments would be appreciated!

```
com.worklight.common.Logger$SendLogsRequestListener(4274): Logger$SendLogsRequestListener.onFailure in Logger.java:1726 :: Failed to POST data from file /data/data/${APP_NAME}/files/analytics.log.0.send due to: HTTP response code: 500
```

Answer (score 1):

On a successful adapter call or WLClient connection to the server, the client will attempt to automatically send logs to the server. It looks like something bad is happening on the autosend for adapters. A temporary workaround would be to disable this auto sending behavior by calling

```
WL.Logger.setAutoSendLogs(false)
```

But you can only use this call if you do not wish for logs to be sent automatically. If you do wish to have this working properly, I'd suggest opening a PMR so that it can be determined if this is an error in your application or an actual defect.